# validate different date formats

Tags: php, regex, validation

I'm in trouble, I need to validate a date that coincides with different date formats, for example

```
18-11-1991
1991-11-18
18/11/1991
1991/11/18
```

I need to validate that the date is as string, matches any of those 4 formats, if not, send an error but I can not think how, seek validation methods used to one of the formats, I happened to replicate for the 4 but as only difference is 1 and not in the 4? Please help.

Comment: It is not possible if you don't know where is the month and where is the day when the day is lower than 13. (but you can always have the year). In other words, you must to restrict the possible formats.

Comment: Aaa ok, what happens is that I'm walking an Excel file that is filled with different dates, so I can not restrict incoming data, but if I can validate from controller, let's see what I can do.

Comment: @sioei: As I said, you can do nothing (or only assumptions). However, if you grab a lot of dates from the document, you can deduce the used format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete date check because it is possible to build invalid dates but maybe it is sufficient for your purpose (and it's not possible to detect formats where date and month are positioned vice versa when no value is greater than 12 - and in my code also when no value is greater 19). I just convert all formats to iso date because it's good for sorting or to use it with mysql:

```
$dates = array();
$dates[] = "18-11-1991";
$dates[] = "1991-11-18";
$dates[] = "18/11/1991";
$dates[] = "1991/11/18";
$dates[] = "1991 11 18";

foreach($dates as $date) {
    $iso_date = "";
    if(preg_match("/^([0-3][0-9])-([0-1][0-9])-([0-9]{4})\$/",$date,$reg)) {
        $iso_date = $reg[3]."-".$reg[2]."-".$reg[1];
    } elseif(preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9])\$/",$date,$reg)) {
        $iso_date = $date;
    } elseif(preg_match("/^([0-3][0-9])\/([0-1][0-9])\/([0-9]{4})\$/",$date,$reg)) {
        $iso_date = $reg[3]."-".$reg[2]."-".$reg[1];
    } elseif(preg_match("/^([0-9]{4})\/([0-1][0-9])\/([0-3][0-9])\$/",$date,$reg)) {
        $iso_date = $reg[1]."-".$reg[2]."-".$reg[3];
    }
    if(empty($iso_date)) {
        echo "<br>ERROR: date $date doesn't match one of the supported formats.";
    } else {
        echo "<br>$date = $iso_date";
    }
}
```

This will output:

```
18-11-1991 = 1991-11-18
1991-11-18 = 1991-11-18
18/11/1991 = 1991-11-18
1991/11/18 = 1991-11-18
ERROR: date 1991 11 18 doesn't match one of the supported formats.
```

---

EDIT: If you like you can add a check on iso_date if it is a valid date:

```
$p = explode("-",$iso_date);
if(count($p)==3 and checkdate($p[1],$p[2],$p[1])) {
    echo " (date is valid)";
}
```